# Entity Framework5.0.0, not creating model1.tt code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ado.net, entity-framework-5

I have an issue in entity framework.
When I add an item ADO.net and connect to my database. After creating the ADO.net file, mode1.tt is created, but it doesnt have any auto generated code.

Can anyone please guide me in that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is a visual studio bug. When you build your project it will crash. After reopen your VS, and rebuild your code its will be fixed.